# Which rule allows for the following reduction?

Tags: parsing, grammar

Let's say I have the following SQL statement:

```
SELECT 1 + myField + 2
```

If we want to reduce the expression at the parsing phase before sending it to SQL, we could turn it into:

```
SELECT 3 + myField
```

What is the name of the rule that allows this? Another example being:

```
SELECT myField * (1 + myField * 2 + 3)
```

Would turn into:

```
SELECT myField * (4 + (myField * 2) )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's usually called "constant folding" (which should be a good search term) and it's easier to do as a transformation on the AST than trying to do it while you parse, precisely because of the reordering which is evident in your examples.

Comment: I see, thanks for the answer. By the way, could you please clarify what you mean by "It's easier to do it on the AST than while you parse" ? Maybe you could show an example on the 1 + myField + 2 item on the difference between doing it one way vs the other ?

Comment: @david: i don't know how to constant-fold `2+x+3` without constructing an AST, although that doesn't mean that there's no way to do it. With an AST, you can rotate the parse tree to concentrate constants to the right (or to the left, if you prefer) and then if you create or find a node whose operands are both constant, you simply replace the subtree with a single constant node. Languages with one-pass compilers typically only constant fold expressions like `x+2+3`.